# Java CSV: Read/Write CSV with multiple header lines

Tags: csv, export-to-csv, opencsv, supercsv, rfc4180

I'm a noob in CSV processing using Java.

How can I read/write multiple header CSV in Java. For example:

Data in hand after multiple joins (say from a table).

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
|student_id | name | year | subject_id | marks| total_marks |
-------------------------------------------------------------
|STD01      | ABC  |2001  | SUB01      | 80   | 155         |
|STD01      | ABC  |2001  | SUB02      | 75   | 155         |
|STD02      | XYZ  |2001  | SUB01      | 85   | 85          |
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

The above data to be represented in below format in CSV - they differ in the first column which identifies them either as ALL or IND

```
ALL, STUDENT_ID, NAME, YEAR, TOTAL_MARKS
IND, STUDRNT_ID, NAME, YEAR, SUBJECT_ID, MARKS
ALL, STD01, ABC, 2001, 155
IND, STD01, ABC, 2001, SUB01, 80
IND, STD01, ABC, 2001, SUB02, 75
ALL, STD02, XYZ, 2001, 85
IND, STD02, XYZ, 2001, SUB01, 85
```

Exporting them as the joined table would mean I have the ALL column in every line which is not desired.

Any clues or useful tools suggestion much appreciated!

Comment: Hi Jake,
why would you want a multi line header? How in the CSV do you know which line corresponds to which header line? Do you have a logic for that? And why not simply export it as the view/table from the multiple join result?

Comment: @lucniner if you can see there is first column with entry ALL/IND (Total/Individual), this differentiates the data rows to match the header rows. If we simply export it as a view/table then each row will have total aggregations which is not desired. So individual rows are rearranged in individual/aggregate rows

Comment: Hi @Jake,
Ah, I get your point - have maybe a look at [any of these tools](https://mvnrepository.com/search?q=csv) which might help you - I once used the apache commons csv for a similar issue

Comment: Hi @lucniner thanks for advice. But there also it's processed using single header. I can't find any resource where multiple headers are handled!

Comment: Hi @Jake,
then you probably need to write your own custom solution by iterating over every line of the file and handle them according.

Answer (score 0):

I don't now if this will help but maybe this class of mine will help you.
It takes a list of objects and returns a CSV file for you. Maybe you can go check out the code in the class just to see what I did
https://github.com/ernst223/spread-sheet-exporter

```
SpreadSheetExporter spreadSheetExporter = new SpreadSheetExporter(List<Object>, "Filename");
File fileCSV = spreadSheetExporter.getCSV();
```